# Don't bring a knife to a gunfight

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I need a "softer" analogy that means the same thing as "Don't bring a knife to a gunfight" or "It's like bringing a knife to a gunfight".

Comment: What aspects of the thing do you want to keep? "Don't expect to be prepared without doing much.", "Violence can escalate beyond expectations.", and "Don't waste time on improper preparation." are all aspects of that particular analogy. (not intended to be a complete list) Also, what do you mean by "softer"?

Answer (score 2):

"Don't get caught with your pants down."

(Assuming lack of sufficient preparation is the key aspect desired, this is about the softest analogy I thought of.)

Answer (score 2):

> [Like …bringing pennies {or pocket change} to a high-stakes poker
>   game](https://books.google.com/books?id=31b7w75__S4C&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=%22pennies+to+a+high-stakes+poker+game%22&source=bl&ots=9Yjefm46bW&sig=Z8OQl_2nt989Pjalgn7kA47t7QU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-8ff92PfKAhUJ8j4KHdtaBYoQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22pennies%20to%20a%20high-stakes%20poker%20game%22&f=false)

would be a less violent, perhaps “softer” way to express the idea.
(from ‘The Big Picture: Filmmaking Lessons from a Life on the Set’ By Tom Reilly, via Google Books)

Answer (score 1):

short and direct:
you can't put out a fire by peeing on it
(answer inspired by the writings of Jonathan Swift)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say preparation is key:

> [**luck/chance/fortune favours the prepared.**](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Louis_Pasteur)

Answer (score 0):

If what you're wanting to do is avoid the harsher violent connotations, you can get creative and create a variant on the same phrase.

> Don't bring Lada (or some other slow car) to a drag race.
>
> Don't bring a wiffle bat to the Major League.
>
> Don't bring high heels to a 100m sprint.